# PHP email form not working,,

Tags: php, html, email

I had an email form working before with what I believe is this code.
But all of a sudden it's not shooting out anymore emails.

Here's my code.

---

HTML

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <div class="grid_6">
            <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name">
            <input type="text" name="subject" value="" placeholder="Phone">
            <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="grid_6 omega"><textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <span style="float:left; margin-left:18px;">
                <input type="reset" class="contact_btn" value="Clear Form">
             <input type="submit" class="contact_btn send_btn" value="Send">
          </span>
    </center>
</form>
```

And PHP

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $msg = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);

    $to = "hello@darrylhuffman.com";
    $subject = 'Portfolio message from' .$name;
    $message = $msg;
    $from = $email;
    $headers = "From:" . $email;

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "Thank you for your message";
}

?>
```

Probably it's a beginner mistake, but I'm stumped.  Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What's "not working" about it?

Comment: Done any basic debugging? checked `var_dump($_POST)`? captured/checked the return value of the `mail()` call? Checked your mail server's logs to see what happens after PHP hands over the email?

Comment: What do you mean, `with what I believe is this code`? What code worked and what is the difference with the current code?

Comment: Maybe you should configure your SMTP.

Comment: What about your MTA settings ?

Comment: You don't appear to be actually posting a var called `submit` so the code isn't being executed...

Comment: I am using the same code I believe, but there has been a lot of carrying over.  The thing that's not working about it is it wont echo the "Thank you for your message" And the email is not sent.

Comment: My suggestion: use php mailer. mail() function is unreliable

Comment: What a mess of code... your `Phone` field is named `subject` or vice-versa and you're setting your `$msg` to `$_POST['email']`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just getting started with PHP.  I'm 15, cut me some slack!  lol

Comment: Spelling mistakes have nothing to do with PHP and you're more than old enough to read them.  Just slow down and take your time.

Comment: You're correct, they don't.  I obviously wasn't thinking correctly.  At least I'm trying.

Comment: Don't take the criticisms personally.  We're only here to help so keep trying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're checking for a "submit" field that isn't defined, add the name to your input

```
<input type="submit" class="contact_btn send_btn" value="Send" name="submit">
```

Comment: I can't believe I over looked this.  I didn't name my button 'submit'.  Beginners mistake, thank you! :)   (I'll mark as answer once I can.)

Comment: @Xatenev on all servers? I'm getting **Submit is not set** when using this: `echo isset($_POST['submit']) ? "Submit is set" : "Submit is not set";` on my local dev box and posting the OPs form? **Unless** I add `name="submit"` to the submit button as per this answer.