# php form data not being submitted to DB

Tags: php, html, forms

this is my 3rd post, I just wanted to thank everybody for being patient and helping me out.

So here's my issue, i'm trying to have this form submit to itself and pass the data to the DB on submit.

I'm not seeing any records added to the DB on the submit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","project1");
// Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
          {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          }
// check variables set
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $site_code = $_POST['site_code'];
    $site_name = $_POST['site_name'];
    $site_address = $_POST['site_address'];
        $site_city = $_POST['site_city'];
    $site_postalcode = $_POST['site_postalcode'];
    $province = $_POST['province'];
        $country = $_POST['country'];
}
// Query from Countries table
$query_countries = "select * from countries";
$country_results = mysqli_query($con,$query_countries);
$number_of_returns_country = mysqli_num_rows($country_results);
// Query from Provinces Table
$query_provinces = "select * from provinces";
$provinces_results = mysqli_query($con,$query_provinces);
$number_of_returns_province = mysqli_num_rows($provinces_results);

//insert form values into sites table
$sql_site="INSERT INTO sites (site_code, site_name, site_address, site_city, site_postalcode, id_province, id_county)
        VALUES
        ('$_POST[site_code]','$_POST[site_name]','$_POST[site_address]','$_POST[site_city]','$_POST[site_postalcode]','$_POST[province]','$_POST[country]')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql_site);        
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Insert Site into DB</h1>
    <h2 class="button"><a href=/index.html>Home</a></h2>
    <h2 class="button"><a href=/insert.php>add site</a></h2>
    <h2 class="button"><a href=/delete.html>delete site</a></h2>
    <h2 class="button"><a href=/search.html>search site</a></h2>
        <form class="insert" action="insert.php" method="post">
                <h3>Site Info</h3>
                        Site code: <input type="text" name="site_code"><br>
                        Site name: <input type="text" name="site_name"><br>
                        Address: <input type="text" name="site_address"><br>
                        City: <input type="text" name="site_city"><br>
                        Postal code: <input type="text" name="site_postalcode"><br>
                        Province: <select name="province">
                                        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($provinces_results)){ ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['province'];?></option>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                </select><br>
                        Country: <select name="country">
                                        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($country_results)){ ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['country'];?></option>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                </select><br>
                <h3>Site Contact Info</h3>
                        Site contact name: <input type="text" name="site_contact_name"><br>
                        Phone number 1: <input type="number" name="site_contact_number1"><br>
                        Phone number 2: <input type="number" name="site_contact_number2"><br>
                        Email address: <input type="email" name="site_contact_email"><br> 
                        <input type="submit">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You still have to execute your insert query.

Comment: [**SQL injection ALERT**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)

Comment: Thought I'd seen something very similar recently : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865880/php-email-form-not-working/22865962#comment34886362_22865962 ... `<input type="submit" />` won't actually pass a variable called `submit` through to PHP unless you give it the name `submit`, so `isset($_POST['submit'])` will never evaluate to true and your code will never execute... except it your case it's just that none of the variables in that block will be set.

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't thrown you an error `[‘site_code’]` along with all the others having those funky quotes.

Comment: I think it's just the way it copied and pasted out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is $sql_site storing a mySQL command. The mySQL command in $sql_site needs to be run with the `mysqli_query` function

```
//insert values into sites table
$sql_site="INSERT INTO sites (site_code, site_name, site_address, site_city, site_postalcode)
       VALUES
        ('$_POST[site_code]','$_POST[site_name]','$_POST[site_address]','$_POST[site_city]','$_POST[site_postalcode]')";

mysqli_query($con,$sql_site);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This,
First Of all you have change the form action

```
<form class="insert" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
```

and move the insert query inside the

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

  // insert query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after declaring `$sql_site`

```
mysqli_query($con,$sql_site);
```